# Intergrate elasticsearch with multiple mongodb in docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have a implemented a microservice architecture with several servers and databases. I have installed elasticsearch with docker and when I do docker-compose up, everything seems to run fine.

However I would like to integrate the elasticsearch with the several databases (2 mongodb in this sample below) in the system. How do I synch the two mongodb in two different containers with elasticsearch so that I can search them?

```
client:
  container_name: client
  stdin_open: true
  build:
    context: ./client
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - './client:/app'
  ports:
    - '1000:3000'
  environment:
    - NODE_ENV=development
    - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true

weatherdb:
  container_name: weather-db
  image: mongo
  restart: always
  ports:
    - '2002:27017'
  volumes:
    - ./weather_service/weather_db:/data/db
  networks:
    - backend

weather-service:
  container_name: weather-service
  build: ./weather_service
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "1002:3000"
  depends_on:
    - weatherdb
  links:
    - elasticsearch
  networks:
    - backend


newsdb:
  container_name: news-db
  image: mongo
  restart: always
  ports:
    - '2003:27017'
  volumes:
    - ./news_service/news_db:/data/db
  networks:
    - backend

news-service:
  container_name: news-service
  build: ./news_service
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "1003:3000"
  depends_on:
    - newsdb
  links:
    - elasticsearch
  networks:
    - backend

elasticsearch:
  image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.4.0
  container_name: elasticsearch
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 9200:9200
    - 9300:9300
  environment:
    ES_JAVA_OPTS: '-Xms512m -Xmx512m'
    network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
    network.host: 0.0.0.0
    discovery.type: single-node
  volumes:
    -  ./elasticsearch/esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  networks:
    - backend
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple to just add a `elasticsearch docker section` in any docker-compose file and start it, all these are independent docker containers and as long as their exposed port on host is not interfering each other and you have the correct configuration in place it should work.

Please refer [elasticsearch multi-docker installation using docker file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-compose-file) for more info.

**NOTE: You have not mentioned what exact issue you are facing, you have mentioned everything ie all docker containers are running file, so please explain in detail what exactly you are trying to solve**

Comment: So I have tried to edit the question but basically I would like to understand how to index the different databases using elasticsearch. How do I synch them?